# Jquery get difference between two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi and thanks in advance.
Just a simple question, I have two variables:

var x = 'abc';

var y = 'ac';

I would like to compare them and get the difference between them, this result:

diff = 'b';

Comment: SOoooo what did you try? Did you search, I am sure this has been asked many times before.

Comment: Why is jquery needed for this?

Comment: Split the `x` variable and filter it out.

Comment: Try http://vanilla-js.com/. This framework is quite suitable for such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the `x` variable using the **[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator)**, then filter all elements which are present in the `y` variable, using **[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter)** and **[Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/indexOf)**.

```js
var x = 'abc',
    y = 'ac',
    diff = [...x].filter(v => [...y].indexOf(v) == -1);
    
    console.log(diff);
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I had never seen such operators in js/jquery.

Comment: The above code will not return anything if `x = 'aba'` and `y = 'ab'` since it is just doing an `.indexOf()`

change it to:
`diff = [...x].filter((v, idx) => [...y][idx] !== v);` to return the precise difference.